# Как сгруппировать данные по клиенту, с разрывом дат?

Tags: sql

Имеется таблица вида
имя клиента , дата начала подписки , дата конца подписки.
ПО одному клиенту может быть много записей, но между датами бывают разрывы.
Как сгруппировать по клиенту min date max date в рамках непрерывности?

на выходе получить:
1 2020-01-01 2020-01-31
1 2020-02-01 2020-02-05
1 2020-02-08 2020-02-28

и тд

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Даты в кучу, начало +1, конец -1, посчитать сумму с накоплением, ноль - конец слитного периода, не-ноль после нуля или NULL - начало.

Comment: а как потом группировать данные?